# Let $A$ be any uncountable set, and let $B$ be a countable subset of $A$. Prove that the cardinality of $A = A - B $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, cardinals

I am going over my professors answer to the following problem and to be honest I am quite confused :/ Help would be greatly appreciated!

> Let $A$ be any uncountable set, and let $B$ be a countable subset of $A$. Prove that $|A| = |A - B|$

The answer key that I am reading right now follows this idea:

It says that $A-B$ is infinite and proceeds to define a new denumerable subset $A-B$ as $C$. Of course since $C$ is countably infinite then we can write $C$ as ${c1,c2,c3...}$

Once we have a set $C$, we know that the union of $C$ and $B$ must be denumerable (from another proof) since $B$ is countable and $C$ is denumerable.

This is where I start to have trouble. The rest of the solution goes like this...

Since the union of $C$ and $B$ is denumerable, there is a bijective function $f$ that maps the union of $C$ and $B$ to $C$ again. The solution then proceeds to define another function $h$ that maps $A$ to $A-B$.

I am just so lost. The thing is I don't even understand the *point* of constructing a new subset $C$ or defining functions like $f$ or $h$.

So I suppose my question is in general, how would one approach this problem? I am not mathematically inclined unfortunately, and a lot of the steps in almost all of these problems seems arbitrary and random. Help would be *really* appreciated on this problem and some general ideas on how to solve problems like these!!!

Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the uncountable set $A$ and its countable subset $B$. You want to show that $|A\setminus B|=|A|$, i.e., that there is a bijection between $A$ and $A\setminus B$. To see what that would mean, let’s imagine for a moment that we already have such a bijection $h:A\to A\setminus B$. $A$ is the union of the disjoint sets $B$ and $A\setminus B$, and $h$ is a bijection, so $h[A]$, which is $A\setminus B$, is the union of the disjoint sets $h[B]$ and $h[A\setminus B]$, as in the sketch below. And because $h$ is a bijection, we know that $B$ and $h[B]$ have the same cardinality; in particular, $h[B]$ is countable. In other words, if we’re to have this bijection $h$, we need to have some countable subset $h[B]$ of $A\setminus B$ that $h$ matches up with the subset $B$ of $A$. The set $C$ of your proof is going to be that set.

[image]

We know that $A\setminus B$ has a countably infinite subset $C$, and we know from an earlier result that $B\cup C$ is countably infinite. This means that $|B\cup C|=|C|$: there is a bijection $f:B\cup C\to C$. We can now use $f$ to build the desired bijection $h:A\to A\setminus B$ quite easily. We’ll split $A$ into two pieces, $B\cup C$ and the rest, which is $A\setminus(B\cup C)=(A\setminus B)\setminus C$; these are shown in red and white, respectively, in the lefthand set in the picture below. We’ll use the bijection $f$ to map $B\cup C$ to $C$, and we’ll use the identity map $\mathrm{id}$ to send $(A\setminus B)\setminus C$ to itself. Combining these two bijections gives us a bijection, which I’ll call $h$, from $A$ to $A\setminus $B$, as in the picture below.

[image]

Formally we define $h:A\to A\setminus B$ by

$$h(a)=\begin{cases}
f(a),&\text{if }a\in B\cup C\\\\
a,&\text{if }a\in(A\setminus B)\setminus C\;.
\end{cases}$$

The key idea is simply that all countably infinite sets are the same size, so we can find a bijection between any two of them. We use that fact to find the bijection $f$ that ‘collapses’ $B\cup C$ into $C$; then we leave all of the other elements of $A$ alone (i.e., those in $(A\setminus B)\setminus C$), and the net effect is to collapse $A$ into $A\setminus B$ with the bijection $h$.

Comment: Wow! What an explanation!! The diagram helped tremendously! Thank you so much! However, I am still not convinced why we need the set $C$. Could we have not just said, well $|B|$ must be equal to $|h[b]|$ and the $|A-B|$ must be equal to $|h[A-B]|$? Could we have not constructed our function $h$ like that? I understand how the solution works with the set $C$ but feel as though it would also work only with set $B$.

Comment: @nicefella: You’re welcome! The idea is to build $h$ so that it leaves most of $A\setminus B$ alone. But we need to set aside a bit of $A\setminus B$ into which we collapse $B$. The easiest way to do this is to reserve a countably infinite amount of space $-$ that’s $C$ $-$ and then collapse $B$ **and** $C$ into that reserved space. I don’t see any nice way to do this without $C$.

Comment: Ah yes! That makes sense! Excellent and thanks again :)

Comment: @nicefella: Glad to have helped.

Comment: Reading this more closely, don't you mean "We’ll use the bijection $f$ to map B∪C to **C**." [ Paragraph between the two diagrams.] @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Wilson: Yep, that was definitely a typo. Thanks!

Comment: Wow what an explanation and answer @BrianMScott! If l had more profs like you,l’d have MA or even PHD. Crying over spilt milk is not profitable

Comment: @Eudoxus: Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

$|A-B|\leq |A|$ is obvious.

For the reverse inequality, 
Use $|A|=|A\times A|$. 
Denote the bijection $A\rightarrow A\times A$ by $\phi$, then $\phi(B)$ embeds into a countable subset of $A\times A$.

Then consider the projection $\pi_1$ onto the first coordinate, of the set $\phi(B)$. 
Namely $\pi_1 \phi(B)$.

Since $|\pi_1\phi(B)|\leq |B|$, and $|B|<|A|$, we see that $A-\pi_1\phi(B)$ is nonempty. Pick any element $x \in A-\pi_1\phi(B)$, then we see that 
$\{x\}\times A$ embeds into $(A\times A)-\phi(B)$.

This gives the reverse inequality $|A|\leq |A-B|$.

Comment: This short argument, unfortunately, implicitly uses the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, whereas the accepted answer does not!

Answer (score 2):

Your answer key is right, but I think it can be describe more simply.

We have $A$ uncountable and $B$ countable.  Since $A-B$ is infinite, it contain another countable set $C$.  So there is a bijection $C\rightarrow B\cup C$ as you note.  Now let $D=(A-B)-C$, so $A-B=C\cup D$, and therefore $A=B\cup C\cup D$, all three of which are disjoint from one another. Since you have the bijection $C\rightarrow B\cup C$, you clearly have another bijection $(C)\cup D\rightarrow (B\cup C)\cup D$, but by construction that is the bijection $A-B\rightarrow A$.

But why is it done this way?  It's kind of a trick.  The key is realizing that you needed to separate both $A$ and $A-B$ into a countable piece, and another piece whose cardinality may not be countable.  Further, you need that questionable piece to be the *same* set on both sides of the bijection: that's $D$ in my example.  The trick is that the countable piece is different on each side of the bijection ($C$ vs. $B\cup C$), but since both are countable you get a bijection anyway!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I just realised that this solution is exactly the same as the trb456's answer. I will leave it anyway, because it is explained slightly differently.

Brian's answer is very elegant and nicely explained. I believe I solved it in a different manner using the theorem for the existence of at least one uncountable subset. I am a novice with set theory however, so there might be mistakes, redundancies and unnecessarily complicated reasoning.

First off, for later clarity let $\hat A :=A\backslash B$. We know we may find a countable subset $C = \{c_1, c_3,...,c_{2n-1},...\}$ in $\hat{A}$. As has already been discussed, it follows that there exists a bijection between $C$ and $B$, i.e. an equivalence $C\sim B$. The following paragraph is trying to show how we may then find an **un**countable subset $D$ such that $D\cap C = \emptyset$ (i.e. have no elements in common), which will have a very useful second property.

Consider a second countable subset $E = \{c_2, c_4,...,c_{2n},...\}$. As the union of two countable sets is countable there is an equivalence $E\cup C \sim E$. We may extend this equivalence so that $(E\cup C)\cup (\hat{A}\backslash (E\cup C)) \sim E \cup (\hat{A}\backslash (E\cup C))$, by transforming $x\in \hat{A}\backslash (E\cup C)$ to itself. But this is the same as $\hat{A} \sim \hat{A}\backslash C$. Thus we have found the uncountable subset $D=\hat{A}\backslash C$ that I mentioned previously.

Now for the kicker. We have because of the above that $D\cup C \sim \hat{A}\cup B$, by sending $x\in D$ to $\hat{A}$ and $x\in C$ to $B$. But $D\cup C = \hat{A}$ and $\hat{A}\cup B = A$. Thus $A\backslash B \sim A$.