# Do these two sets have the same cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A is Uncountable and B is Countable. 
Does $\left | A \right | = \left | A \cup B \right |$ ?

I was thinking
build a countable set of distinct ordered elements $A_{N}= \left \{  \right. a_{N}: N\epsilon \mathbb{N}\left.  \right \}  $ where $A_{N}\subset{A}$.

Then define    $  f: A_{N}\rightarrow{B}, f(a_{N})=b_{N}$.

Next define  $  f: A\setminus A_{N}\rightarrow{A}, f(a_{n})=a_{n-N},\forall n>N$.

So we have two bijections and thus by taking the union $\left |A_{N} \cup A\setminus A_{N}\right | = \left | {B}\cup A  \right | $.

Does this work out?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/355183/12042). Your $A\cup B$ corresponds to the set $A$ of that answer, and your $B\setminus A$ corresponds to the $B$ there.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. We are playing Hilbert's hotel here.
Once we have a countably infinite subset $A_{\Bbb N}=\{\,a_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}$  of $A$, we find a bijection of $A$ with $A\setminus A_{2\Bbb N}$, where $A_{2\Bbb N}=\{\,a_{2n}\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}$ is another countably infinite subset of $A$:
$$a\mapsto\begin{cases}a&\text{if }a\notin A_{\Bbb N}\\
a_{2n+1}&\text{if }a=a_n\end{cases} $$
This allows us to "stow away" the countably infinite set $B$.

If $B$ is countable and finite, use 
$$a\mapsto\begin{cases}a&\text{if }a\notin A_{\Bbb N}\\
a_{n+|B|}&\text{if }a=a_n\end{cases} $$
instead to "make room" for $B$.

Comment: What do you mean by "countable and finite"? Countable is defined as far as I know to be infinite. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of $A_N$ is odd. $N$ can't be both an index inside the definition of the set, and a parameter outside. You should write
$$A'=\{a_N;N\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
Then your second map does not make sense since you never define an integer $N$. On top of it, it seems that neither map takes values outside of $A'$.