# Proof that $2^{\mathbb N}$ and $\mathbb R$ have same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I want to show that $2^{\mathbb N}$, the set of $0/1$-sequences has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$. This fact is usually taken for granted, but the usual interpretation of $\mathbb R$ as binary sequences does not give a bijection, for example $1 = 0.111111\ldots$ and so on.

The set $P := \{ u.v\overline{1} \mid u,v \mbox{ finite sequences} \}$ is countable, and by the above construction we have $\mbox{card}(\mathbb R) = \mbox{card}(2^{\mathbb N} \setminus P)$. Now I guess the following property holds, if some set $X$ is infinite, and $Y$ is countable, then $\mbox{card}(X) = \mbox{card}(X \cup Y)$. As take some countable subset $Z \subseteq X$ and construct a bijective function $f : Z \to Z \cup Y$, for example by interlacing the elements of $X$ and $Y$. Then the function
$$
 g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  x & \mbox{ if } x \in X \setminus Y \\
  f(x) & \mbox{ if } x \in Y
\end{array}\right.
$$
maps surjectively onto $X \cup Y$. Hence $\mbox{card}(X) \ge \mbox{card}(X \cup Y)$, and as $\mbox{card}(X) \le \mbox{card}(X \cup Y)$ we have equality. Using this gives $\mbox{card}(2^{\mathbb N}) = \mbox{card}(2^{\mathbb N}\setminus P \cup P) = \mbox{card}(2^{\mathbb N} \setminus P)$.

But is there an easier way, guess there is some way to see it instantly, as $\mbox{card}(2^{\mathbb N}) = \mbox{card}(\mathbb R)$ is taken for granted in even the most basic introductions to analysis; so I guess even the novice to mathematics should see it easily?

Comment: How exactly are you mapping $\mathbb{R}$ to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$?  In particular, how do you handle the decimal point and negative numbers? (These are not hard to handle, but since you seem to be looking for a complete self-contained proof you should be careful about these things.)

Comment: Would you be ok with having injective maps in both ways?

Comment: It's much easier to construct an injection both ways. $2^{\Bbb N}\to\Bbb R$ by interpreting the sequences as base ten decimal expansions, and $\Bbb R\to 2^{\Bbb N}$ by first taking a bijection $\Bbb R\to(0,1)$ and then take the binary expansion of every number there, choosing the one that ends in all $0$ for the numbers that have two expansions.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh yes, thanks for pointing out! A similar argument comes to my mind, code a real number as triple with sign, integer part, fractional part, and using in some way $|X \times Y| = |Y|$ if $X$ is countable and $Y$ is infinite (which might be a corollar of $|Y \times Y| = |Y|$ for infinite $Y$, guess this to be true). Have not thought about the details, but gets also very technical soon...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Preferably without Schröder-Bernstein, as I would not consider this elementary in the sense that a novice could possibly know it.

Answer (score 1):

One easier way is this. Consider the set $[0,1]$ in reals and their binary representation. We map a set $A$ to a decimal $d$ where  the $n$'th decimal is $1$ if $n\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. There is the natural issue of us having multiple representations, such as $0.1=0.011111\ldots$, however from all of these we pick one of the pair, wether it is the infinite decimal expansion or the finite one doesn't matter. And make these we picked a set. Now this set, let's call it $S$ has a cardinality less than or equal to $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$, however as this involves finite decimal expansions we know all of these are rationals so $|S|=|\Bbb N|$. Now we recall that for infinite sets we have
$$|K-F|=|K|$$
when their cardinality differ such that $|K|>|F|$. as such we have
$$|\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)-S|=|\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)|$$
As such our former surjection $f$ can be made to be injective by restricting it now to $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)-S$ and as such we have a bijection.

Now from here we use the function
$$\tan(\frac{\pi(x-1)}{2})$$
to go from $(0,1)$ to $\Bbb R$, as removing the two end points does not change the cardinality.

Addition: 
To prove $$|K-F|=|K|$$
for $|K|>|F|$ look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/355183).

Comment: What should $\mbox{max}(K,F)$ mean? Or do you mean $\mbox{max}(|K|, |F|)$? But then for example $|\emptyset - \mathbb N| = 0 \ne \mbox{max}(|\emptyset|, |\mathbb N|) = |\mathbb N|$?

Comment: I meant the latter, typoed

Comment: Makes sense, but do you have any elementary proof that $|K - F| = \max\{|K|, |F|)$ for $|K| \ge |F|$ (the case $|\mathbb R|$ and $|\mathbb N|$ would be enough here)?

Comment: For those sets it is fairly simple, how familiar are you with set theory? I ask as it determined how I add it.

Comment: I know naive set theory, so I am familiar with basic operations, but no advanced stuff.

Comment: I'll add it tomorrow then

Comment: Incluided a link to the answer of that proof.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using Cantor-Bernstein - obviously $|\mathbb{R}| \leq |2^{\mathbb{N}}|$, because every rule can be expressed as a binary sequence. Likewise, $|2^{\mathbb{N}}| \leq |\mathbb{R}|$ because we can interpret binary sequences uniquely as reals expressed in base $3$ (that just happen not to have any $2$'s). I'd call this about as elementary as it gets, second only to a truly natural bijection.

If you really want a bijection, the best option I can give is a kind of hack. First, map all of the reals that aren't dyadic rationals to their unique base-$2$ representation. Then, take the dyadic rational $\frac{2n + 1}{2^m}$ to the ``vanilla'' ($\ldots 00000\ldots$) representation of $\frac{2(n/2) + 1}{2^m}$ if $n$ is even or the other ($\ldots 1111\ldots$) representation of $\frac{2((n-1)/2) + 1}{2^m}$ if $n$ is odd. I don't think this is very simple, but I doubt there are simpler bijections.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest approach is probably to first show that $\textbf{2}^\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as the open interval $(0,1)$ and then show that $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.

First consider all infinite $0-1$-sequences other than the constant sequences (of $0$'s and $1$'s, respectively). To every such sequence $s$ corresponds a unique $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ given by

$$x \in S \iff s_i = 1 $$

It is not hard to see that we thereby obtain a bijection. The binary sequences do not correspond to the binary decimal expansions of the real numbers in the open interval $(0,1)$, as there are real numbers in this interval that have more than one such decimal expansion. However, there are only *countably many* numbers with this property and for each such number there are only *countably many* distinct representations. Therefore, even when these have been omitted, there are still uncountably many $0-1$ sequences left.

To show that $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ consider the bijection $f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$f(x) = \tan({\pi (\frac{1}{2}-x)})$$

Comment: You need to work more. The problem is that real numbers may have two representatives as that sequences that are eventually constant. E.g. .100000000.... equals .0111111111....

Comment: Yes, you identify the binary expansion with subsets of $\mathbb N$, but still I do not see an argument that its no problem that some real numbers have two binary expansion (and hence are associated with two subsets of $\mathbb N$).

Comment: I have tried to deal with the uniqueness issue now; I have updated my answer accordingly.