# How to prove the following: Assume A infinite,B denumerable show that A~$A\cup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume A is infinite,B is denumerable.
Prove A$\approx (A \cup B)$(rewrite)

Reference:

**7.18** Theorem A is an infinite set iff A is equipotent with a proper subset of itself.

**1.20** Theorem If A and B are any classes, then

i) A⊆A∪B and B⊆A∪B.

ii) A∩B⊆A. and A∩B⊆B

*My thoughts on it are as follows* :
By 7.18 if A is infinite then it is equipotent
with a proper subset of itself, so by
1.20(i),A$\subseteq A\cup B$

Then there exist an injective function f:$\omega\mapsto A\cup B$
Check f is bijective once defined.

If A is denumerable ,we know there is a bijective
function f:$\omega\mapsto A\cup B$ and we
have a function g:$A\cup B\mapsto\omega$
Once defined show it is onto

I don’t know how to create brackets for
two functions thus I state “once it is created “
Then ?

I don’t think I can conclude somehow?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of *infinite set*?

Comment: (1)A is infinite iff it has a denumerable subset

Comment: And your definition of *denumerable* is?

Comment: A set is called denumerable if it is in one-to-one correspondence with ω.    
                                                                                                                6.1 Definition The set of the natural numbers is designated by the symbol ω; every element of ω is called a natural number

Comment: In the future, please provide a descriptive title to your questions.

Comment: Ok,I changed title to something more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

If $B\subseteq A$, there is nothing to prove, since in that case $A\cup B=A$, so assume that $B\nsubseteq A$. $A$ is infinite, so it has a denumerable subset $D$.

- Show that $B\cup D$ is denumerable.

Let $f:\omega\to D$ and $g:\omega\to B\cup D$ be bijections. Define

$$h:A\cup B\to A:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
a,&\text{if }a\in A\setminus(B\cup D)\\
f\left(g^{-1}(x)\right),&\text{if }x\in B\cup D\,,
\end{cases}$$

and show that $h$ is a bijection.

(Some of the discussion in my answer to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355049/let-a-be-any-uncountable-set-and-let-b-be-a-countable-subset-of-a-prove) may prove helpful.)

Comment: @Eudoxus: You’re welcome; yes, the recursion theorem definitely comes into play here.

Comment: Thanks, I would not have thought of the part 2 like that . So the Recursion Theorem is in use .  I can’t use the identity inn1.20(I) then Ok

Comment: Two other questions (1) is it possible to prove part 2 using contrapositive technique (2) can I use the  identity A$\subseteq A\cup B$

Comment: @Eudoxus: Oops! I just realized that I completely misread your question: for some reason I thought that you were trying to prove **7.18**. Give me a few minutes to think about it and completely rewrite my answer.

Comment: That has been in the texts. Those are references for my ideas for a proof